# $.post form with facebox and redirect

Tags: asp.net, jquery, postback, http-status-codes, facebox

Using Facebox with .NET (Web Forms) is painful--this primarily HTML site was designed by someone else. I may have IIS (7.5) issues as well. This Facebox pop-up is in a separate file, login.html, that is called from index.html:

```
$k('a[rel*=example_2]').facebox_1({
  loading_image : '/images/loading.gif',
  close_image   : '/images/closelabel.gif'
});
```

and the link to open it

```
<a href="login.html" title="Log In" rel="example_2" id='login'>Log In </a>
```

The form to be submitted with username and password (login.html):

```
<form name="login" method="post" action="#" onsubmit="return false;">
```

and after it's validated (this is working), it posts to login.aspx (login.html):

```
$('form[name="login"]').submit(function () {
    var $loginForm = $('form[name="login"]');
    if ($loginForm.valid()) {
        $.post("Login.aspx", $(this).serialize());
    } else {
        $loginForm.validate();
    }
});
```

The form posts. I can debug it in Visual Studio in the Page_Load method of login.aspx. The last line of the Page_Load method is:

```
Response.Redirect("welcomepage.html");
```

But, the Facebox pop-up remains. Firebug shows the post, It hits the Page_Load method of login.aspx, and the Facebox pop-up doesn't go anywhere. **BUT,** Firebug shows welcomepage.html rendered twice in the Response tab of the XHR (huh? why XHR?) request. I thought $.post did a regular postback. And why isn't my browser actually redirecting.

**Attempted Fix**

If I change the form in login.html to `action='login.aspx'`, I get a 405.0 error method not allowed (**but, it's trying to post to index.html, HUH?**). And I can't figure out how to fix this in IIS 7.5 on Windows 7. I get this error in Visual Studio *and* when deploying locally to IIS. I had read it may have to do with script mapping, handlers, or the fact that I'm posting from an  but I can't find a sufficient fix. Any ideas here? If I can figure out the Facebox redirect, I might not need this fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XmlHttpRequests will **transparently** follow the redirect](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#infrastructure-for-the-send-method), which means the AJAX call that  `$.post()` made *is* getting redirected, and following it...not the actual parent page.

[`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) does *not* do a regular postback, it does an AJAX `POST`, that's probably the source of the confusion, you should use a standard `<form>` if you intend to do a regular, page-changing postback.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So, now it would seem IIS is my problem. Using a standard form with attribute `action='login.aspx'` produces the 405.0 error mentioned in the "Attempted Fix" section above. Is this because .html can't post to .aspx by default?

Comment: @David - What method were you using then?

Comment: Post, as shown above in `form name='login'`. I also remove the submit function binding and the `onsubmit` attribute from the form.

Comment: I think the post is working now, but the other buttons on the page are broken. The other buttons fire `.click()` for other Facebox pop-ups. Should I start a new question for this?

Comment: @David - I would, or add the `click` handlers for those buttons...or if you have a link to the page that I can access that'd work too.  Sorry for the delayed response, was away for a few hours.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the continued help. I tried a click handler earlier, and it behaved the same way. Since this is an external page (login.html) loaded by Facebox, I can't seem to debug the script used to fire the code that used to work (or the click handler I tried for that matter). Will Firebug allow me to add break points in external pages loaded via XHR?

Comment: @David - Yep, though for your click handlers, you may want `.live()` in this case, depending on how they're loaded.

Comment: I will give the .live option a try, but I think Visual Event last told me the event was bound ok. It's just client side validation at this point. new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868273/jquery-validate-may-have-broken-facebox-pop-up